# Excel (XLSX) and locales

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, locale, xlsx

Does opening an .xlsx file in systems with different locales correctly render the content according to locale, regardless of what locale file was originally created in?

e.g. User 1 creates excel file (XLSX) in en-US as "2/7/2019" (Feb 7th 2019)
e.g. User 2 opens this in en-GB locale in Excel application - will he see this content correctly rendered as "7/2/2019" (Feb 7th 2019) according to British convention?

Similarly for time, number formats

Comment: What do you mean by "Similarly for time, number formats"? The thousand and decimal separator is the same for UK and US.

Comment: I meant other locales (e.g. de-de) where the number formats also vary (e.g. dot is not the decimal separator). My intent is for all users of my file who are across locales to see the correct output rendered in their respective locale convention

Comment: I believe that's covered here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/number-formatting

Comment: Select the Date format begin with * symbol.

Answer (score 2):

If the field is formatted as 'Date' or 'Time' using the default Category, then the dates should appear as their local notation **if you use the asterisk notations**. You could of course use 'Custom' Category and set dd/mm/yyyy, but by the sounds of things you want your US users to see mm/dd and your UK users to see dd/mm.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e and refer this image, specifically the comment at the bottom of the dialog.

[image]

Comment: yes - my intent is that regardless of what Locale i save it in (e.g. en-US) users in other locales (e.g. en-GB) should see the date rendered in their default locale format

Comment: Then my work here is done, and you can +1 my answer ;)